# Initialising a constant string in a constructor? C++

Tags: c++, string, constructor, constants

```
//Person declaration
Class Person {
    public:
        Person();
        const String getName() const;
    private:
        const String name;
};

//Person definition
    #include "Person.h"
    Player::Player() {
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
}
```

If I want to initialize the person's name upon creation of the class, using the default constructor and an initialization list, but with the constraint of name_ being a const, how can I go about doing this?

I don't believe an init list for name would work, considering that to my knowledge an init list sets the values upon creation, and with name being a const it wouldn't be modifiable at that point anymore.

So assuming I create a Person(); in another class, how can I initially set their name to const for the duration of that class instance's life time?

Comment: I would not `std::cin >> name;` in the constructor.

Comment: "I don't believe an init list for name would work" It will :).

Comment: Fast responses guys! Thank you, @Galik, what would you recommend as another method of setting the name, with another constraint being that I cannot use a setter.

Comment: @George, could you please clarify how an init list would work for this?

    I've tried Player() : name(n) {
     cin >> n;
    } and such, but I'm unsure if this is the right approach.

Comment: See the @The Aspiring Hacker's answer. You can use the constructor's init list.

Answer (score 5):

Don't prompt for input in the constructor. Move the IO outside of the function and make the constructor take a string as an argument. Then, pass the string from the user to the constructor.

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(const std::string& name)
      : name_(name) {}
    const std::string& getName() const { return name_; }
private:
    const std::string name_;
};
```

...

```
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
Person person(name);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! As a note, what's so bad about taking IO in the constructor?

Comment: As your programs get bigger, it's better practice to treat classes as modular APIs for other code to call and not interweave them with application aspects such as getting input. What if you want to create a `Person` object in which the name is not to be given via the user, for example?

Comment: @casperf1 Rigidity, and the fact you can't initialise a `const` member from the ctor's control scope of its class.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you muchly for the support. Assuming I want to initialise a player object in another class, and access its methods whilst still utilizing this constructor. Can I just call the constructor from the OtherClass.cpp/.h?

Comment: @casperf1 If you use your construct as is, then when you create the player object from OtherClass.cpp, the user will be prompted for input.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function as the initializer:

```
std::string get_name() {
    std::cout << "Name: ";
    std::string nm;
    std::cin >> nm;
    return nm;
}

Person::Person() : name(get_name()) {
}
```